# Maven - Not detecting when compiling main module

Tags: java, maven

I was working on a project, and I decided to code a type of api and implement it on anothers modules, following this architecture:

```
project [core]:
---- src/
---- pom.xml
---- module [parent-1]:
-------- src/
-------- pom.xml
```

Basically, the *parent-1* should shade and implement the *core src* , but when I'm trying to compile, maven just throw a bunch of compilation errors, that says the core source were not found.

```
[ERROR] package com.core.manager does not exists
[ERROR] cannot find symbol: class Manager
so on...
```

#### core project pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.core</groupId>
<artifactId>core</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>parent-1</module>
</modules>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

#### parent module pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.core</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>parent-1</artifactId>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm using *mvn install*, I also tried *mvn package* and *mvn compile* (just because why not).

Thanks for answer and sorry for my weak english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen usage of parent and module pom together. I don't know if it's a valid approach. There are two types of maven modules:

- parent pom holds plugin definitions, artifact versions, properties. All of those can be reused in child modules.
- artifact  - after build it will produce a jar/war/ear

I would see this project like this:

```
parent [parent]:// parent of the project
 --project [core]: // core artifact
 ------ src/
 ------ pom.xml
 --module [parent-1]: // artifact that uses core
 ------src/
 ------pom.xml
```

So your parent pom would have two modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>parent-1</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot about the `-1` in the architecture example.